# If mean=mode, mean=median?

Tags: statistics

> If the mean of a set of data is equal to the mode, is it always equal to the median? Explain why or why not.

I would guess no, but after generating countless sets I cannot find anything that contradicts this

Comment: Using the empirical formula, 3 median = mode + 2 mean, the mean is equal to the mode

Comment: @RajivKaipa "Using the empirical formula, 3 median = mode + 2 mean" Huh? Where does this "empirical" formula come from?

Comment: It is 'emperical', which means that it has been observed. It is an approximation and holds good for perfectly symmetric distributions, which is the  test case.

Comment: I think the definitions of the mean, median and mode in elementary statistics can be of help.

Comment: how would i write the definition of mode mathematically?

Comment: Example: (0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,11). mean=mode=2, median=1.

Comment: $$-10,0,0,1,2,3,4$$